# Dynamically define a function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to write a curve fitting function which returns the optimal parameters a, b and c, here is a simplified example:

```
import numpy
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def f(x, a, b, c):
    return x * 2*a + 4*b - 5*c

xdata = numpy.array([1,3,6,8,10])
ydata = numpy.array([  0.91589774,   4.91589774,  10.91589774,  14.91589774,  18.91589774])
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata)
```

This works fine, but I want to give the user a chance to supply some (or none) of the parameters a, b or c, in which case they should be treated as constants and not estimated. How can I write `f` so that it fits only the parameters not supplied by the user?

Basically, I need to define `f` dynamically with the correct arguments. For instance if `a` was known by the user, `f` becomes:

```
def f(x, b, c):
    a = global_version_of_a
    return x * 2*a + 4*b - 5*c
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking a page from  the [collections.namedtuple playbook](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c2e588a5237a/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l240), you can use exec to "dynamically" define `func`:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import textwrap

funcstr=textwrap.dedent('''\
def func(x, {p}):
    return x * 2*a + 4*b - 5*c
''')
def make_model(**kwargs):
    params=set(('a','b','c')).difference(kwargs.keys())
    exec funcstr.format(p=','.join(params)) in kwargs
    return kwargs['func']

func=make_model(a=3, b=1)

xdata = np.array([1,3,6,8,10])
ydata = np.array([  0.91589774,   4.91589774,  10.91589774,  14.91589774,  18.91589774])
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
print(popt)
# [ 5.49682045]
```

Note the line

```
func=make_model(a=3, b=1)
```

You can pass whatever parameters you like to make_model. The parameters you pass to `make_model` become fixed constants in `func`. Whatever parameters remain become free parameters that `optimize.curve_fit` will try to fit.

For example, above, a=3 and b=1 become fixed constants in `func`. Actually, the `exec` statement places them in `func`'s global namespace. `func` is thus defined as a function of `x` and the single parameter `c`. Note the return value for `popt` is an array of length 1 corresponding to the remaining free parameter `c`.

---

Regarding `textwrap.dedent`: In the above example, the call to `textwrap.dedent` is unnecessary. But in a "real-life" script, where `funcstr` is defined inside a function or at a deeper indentation level, `textwrap.dedent` allows you to write

```
def foo():
    funcstr=textwrap.dedent('''\
        def func(x, {p}):
            return x * 2*a + 4*b - 5*c
        ''')
```

instead of the visually unappealing

```
def foo():
    funcstr='''\
def func(x, {p}):
    return x * 2*a + 4*b - 5*c
'''
```

Some people prefer

```
def foo():
    funcstr=(
        'def func(x, {p}):\n'
        '    return x * 2*a + 4*b - 5*c'
        )
```

but I find quoting each line separately and adding explicit EOL characters a bit onerous. It does save you a function call however.

Comment: Basic question, but I'm having trouble defining funcstr in deeper indentation levels (inside a class). It's throwing indentation errors...

Comment: One more thing. What about passing other variables, for example if "c" was an array I needed to pass in as a global, but do not want to have it in the parameters of f? Thanks.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, just pass it in to `make_model`: e.g. `func=make_model(c=array)`. (It will not show up in the parameters of `f`. It will be accessible to `f`, however.)

Comment: btw, that last example does not work, it is lacking \n newlines between the strings.

Comment: Oh yes, another reason I don't like this method... :)  (Thanks for catching the error.)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a lambda for this purpose.

```
user_b, user_c = get_user_vals()
opt_fun = lambda x, a: f(x, a, user_b, user_c)
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(opt_fun, xdata, ydata)
```

Comment: Does that work if the lambda uses numpy functions? How could I also make the opt_fun call dynamic (I want the user to set paramaters at the top of the script, setting to None where they want the parameter to be fitted).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution based on `curve_fit`, I'd suggest that you wrap your function in a class. Minimal example:

```
import numpy
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

class FitModel(object):
    def f(self, x, a, b, c):
        return x * 2*a + 4*b - 5*c

    def f_a(self, x, b, c):
        return self.f(x, self.a, b, c)

# user supplies a = 1.0
fitModel = FitModel()
fitModel.a = 1.0

xdata = numpy.array([1,3,6,8,10])
ydata = numpy.array([  0.91589774,   4.91589774,  10.91589774,  14.91589774,  18.91589774])
initial = (1.0,2.0)
popt, pconv = curve_fit(fitModel.f_a, xdata, ydata, initial)
```

Comment: This would start to get messy with 5 parameters, the number of functions I need to write goes up fast...

Answer (score 0):

There is already a package that does this:

https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/index.html

From the README:

"LMfit-py provides a Least-Squares Minimization routine and class
with a simple, flexible approach to parameterizing a model for
fitting to data.  Named Parameters can be held fixed or freely
adjusted in the fit, or held between lower and upper bounds.  In
addition, parameters can be constrained as a simple mathematical
expression of other Parameters."

Answer (score -2):

```
def f(x, a = 10, b = 15, c = 25):
    return x * 2*a + 4*b - 5*c
```

If the user doesn't supply an argument for the parameter in question, whatever you specified on the right-hand side of the `=` sign will be used:

e.g.:
`f(5, b = 20)` will evaluate to `return 5 * 2*10 + 4*20 - 5*25` and
`f(7)` will evaluate to `return 7 * 2*10 + 4*15 - 5*25`